# Why when I include the http package inside pubspec.yaml does my Flutter web project not work?

Tags: flutter-web

I've been using Flutter for web for a few days and I've now reached the point where I need to make an HTTP request to an API to fetch some data, but when I include the `http` package inside `pubspec.yaml` and run the app, it does not work, but when I remove the package and re-run the app, it works fine.

This is the error message I get when I run the app after including the `http` package inside `pubspec.yaml`:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Git error. Command: git fetch
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
exit code 69
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add it to pubspec, just import it where you're using it:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```